# New Stack overflow Navbar has bugs in safari

Tags: support, design, top-bar

The new navbar design and styling has bugs in Safari desktop browser, Sorry if i am saying this too early but this should be fixed

[image]

Comment: What version of Safari are you running?

Comment: Safari version 5.1.7